# Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API - Get uploaded images

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I played around with the MS Face API and wonder if there is a possibility to get the uploaded images back? For all uploaded images I get a faceId which can be added to persons and persons to groups and so on. But I have not found a way how to display e.g. the persons which are member in a group.

Or is the concept to save all images on the client and add the received id to the image on the client? Than is the question what happens with the images which are uploaded for face detection?

regards,

Jochen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API doesn't allow the images to be retrieved back. You're right about the general use case, the IDs help you reference the correct image(s) in the application. Often times you'll want to upload a smaller image to the API than what you want to display to the user.

You can always submit feature requests to the team's public backlog over at: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/